# MVC 4 application does not go to default page after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment

I have created an MVC 4 application which targets .NET 4.0. After deploying to my production server, it will show the login page but will not redirect to the default page. However, when I add debugging, I can see that the authentication process works but then the error I am getting is an error that says it can't find my View for my Error Page and then shows my Error Page. It just seems that it will not go to my "Home/Index" page - even when I remove the authorize attribute. Of course the application works in development. Additionally, it will not go to my register page or forgot login page.

My Login Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if(ModelStat.IsValid && _userService.Login(model.UserId, model.Password))
    {
        var user = _userService.GetUser(model.UserId);
        var loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser
        {
            // Build the user for custom IPrincipal
        };
        var userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loggedInUser);
        var compressData = StringCompression.Compress(userData);
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            user.UserId,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
            false,
            compressData);
        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        if(encTicket != null)
        {
            var faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket)
        {
            HttpOnly = true
        };
        Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
    }

    user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
    user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
    _userService.UpdateUser(user);
    _uow.Commit();

    return Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) ? (ActionResult)Redirect(returnUrl) : RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(model);
```

and in my Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if(authCookie != null)
    {
        var decompressedData = StringCompression.Decompress(authTicket.UserData);
        var loggedInUser = JsonConvert.DesrializeObject<LoggedInUser>(decompressedData);
        var currrentUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name)
        {
            // Build the CustomPrincipal from the loggedInUser
        };
        if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = currentUser;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this is enough to give someone an idea of what I may be doing wrong. Somehow I feel that it is something small that I am missing. Thanks in advance.
                                                                 ~InDireStraits

**Update:**

After more troubleshooting, it would seem that the issue may have something to do with the fact that I am using a BaseController for specifying permissions but I am still baffled as to why the application works as intended in my development environment but not in production. To verify my IIS settings I installed the default MVC4 App to production which does not have .NET 4.5, and it runs. I am using VS 2012 so I do have 4.5. Could I somehow be introducing .NET 4.5 classes or functionality even if this targets .NET 4.0?  At any rate, here is my **BaseController code:**

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
    private string _actionKey;
    private const string PermisisionList = "permissionList";
    private Dictionary<string, string> _requiredActionPermissions;
    private static readonly IControllerActionService<ControllerAction> _actionService;

    protected new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.User as CustomPrincipal;
        }
    }

    public BaseController(IControllerActionService<ControllerAction> actionService)
    {
        _actionService = actionService;
    }


    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Check to see if the PermissionList is loaded and load if necessary
        if(!CacheLayer.Exists(PermissionList))
        {
            _requiredActionPermissions = _actionService.GetControllerActionDictionary();
            CacheLayer.Add(_requiredActionPermissions, PermissionList);
        }
        else
        {
            _requiredActionPermission = CacheLayer.Get<Dictionary<string, string>>(PermissionList);
        }
        // Get the Controller/Action of the current request
        _actionKey = string.Format("{0}-{1}", filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName, filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);

        // If the user is authenticated, grab the permissions
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userPermissions = User.Permissions;
           if(!_requiredActionPermissions.Values.Any(a=>a.Equals(_actionKey, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return;
            }
        if(userPermissions.Contains(_requiredActionsPermissions.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Value == _actionKey).Key))
            {
                return;
            }
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/ErrorUnauthorized");
            return;
        }
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if(!_requiredActionPermissions.Values.Any(a=>a.Equals(_actionKey, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url == null)
        { 
            return;
        }
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl)
        {
            return;
        }
        var redirectUrl = string.Format("?returnUrl={0}", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
         filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + redirectUrl, true);
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**: Installed .NET 4.52 on Staging Server and the application now works as intended. The problem is that I will not be able to install this on the production server. I don't understand what it is that 4.5 is fixing that 4.0 does not seem to facilitate. HELLLLLLPPP!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598383/) To summarize, I added an extra parameter to my route config that worked in 4.5 but not in 4.0. Will follow up on the linked question. Thanks